# Why is the video game Braid Turing-complete?

Tags: computability, turing-completeness, computer-games

It's written in wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness#Games that the video game [Braid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braid_(video_game)) is Turing-complete.

I've played Braid before but I can hardly reconcile it with Turing completeness. In what sense is it Turing-complete?

Comment: Well first, I wonder in what sense *any* game is "Turing complete". (For example, what is the input and what is the output?)

Answer (score 1):

Because Braid can simulate a variant of Rush Hour, which is at least PSPACE-hard.

Additionally, Braid itself is undecidable because it can simulate a counter machine which is equivalent to a Turing machine, and thus determining if any general Braid level is solvable is similar to solving the halting problem, which is undecidable.

Comment: How does the first paragraph answer the question? How does the undecidability of a question imply that it is Turing-complete?

Comment: @Raphael I looked over the paper and I saw that their argument was exactly that. The author declares Braid is at least PSPACE because you can simulate a PSPACE game in it and that it is possibly undecidable because you can simulate a Turing machine in it.

Comment: 1) What does it mean if you say "a game is (at least) PSPACE"? Which decision problem are we looking at? 2) Simulating *a* Turing machine does not imply anything about decidability. Again, decidability of *which problem*? 3) Even if you could simulate *all* TMs, "the problem" may be decidable. 4) The question asks about Turing-completeness, not decidability. 5) Undecidability (*of what*?) does not imply Turing-completeness.

Comment: Also, which paper?

Comment: @Raphael https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.0784